# python np.where com duas condições

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,0],
                  'B': [5,0,0,1]})
```

O que eu quero é criar uma coluna 'D', que seja True caso as duas colunas 'A' e 'B' sejam > 0

O que eu já tentei:

```py
x['D'] = x.A > 0 or x.B > 0
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Também tentei:

```py
x['D'] = np.where((x.A >0) or (x.B > 0), True, False)
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui.

```
x['D'] = np.where((x.A > 0) | (x.B > 0), True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você também poderia ter usado o comando `.any(1)`, que verificaria em cada linha do DataFrame se algum dos valores é True, desta forma:

```
x['D'] = (x[['A','B']] > 0).any(1)

    A   B   D
0   1   5   True
1   2   0   True
2   3   0   True
3   0   1   True
```

Caso o seu DataFrame fosse composto apenas pelas colunas A e B, nem seria necessário selecioná-los.

```
x['D'] = (x > 0).any(1)
```